# due to Obfuscation installation of DLL in GAC is getting failed

Tags: windows-installer, obfuscation, gac, signing, dotfuscator

I am facing a problem during installation of my product.
My product(MSI) gets installed successfully if DLLs(under MSI) are not obfuscated. But it fails if I use obfuscated DLL (under MSI).

Error shown during installation is:

```
signature or catalog could not be verified or is not valid
```

Installer(MSI) register DLL's under GAC. If I use obfuscated DLL (packaged with MSI's) then  only this problem occurs. With unobfuscated DLL's this problem doesn't occurs.

Please help me how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Are the assemblies signed BEFORE the obfuscation? If yes, sign them AFTER the obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

Assemblies need to have a strong name before they can be added to the GAC. Your obfuscated dll is not signed anymore. Please sign after obfuscation.